# Average of the numbers given by a linear congruential generator

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, random, simulation

Show that the average of numbers given by a full cicle of a linear congruential generator with full lenght period is $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2m}$, whith $m$ as the module of the generator.

I began by using the definition of a linear congruential generator and the Hull & Dobell theorem, but I got lost in a cycling argument.

Comment: You should define $m$.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, $m$ is the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  if the generator has full period, each possible value must show up once.  What is the average of those?

Comment: If $m$ is the module, it has $m$ different values, with the first one equals cero, so the average is $(m-1)/2$.

Comment: I believe you are to divide once more by $m$ so the output is between $0$ and $1$.  That gives just what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I forgot that output.